# I've been doing Chemistry all day, or I was doing Chemistry all day

Tags: sentence-construction, tense

Is grammatically correct to say: I've been doing Chemistry all day, or I was doing Chemistry all day?

What's the difference between these sentences?

Comment: We should not capitalise subject names (such as 'chemistry') when they are used in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sentences can be correct, but mean slightly different things.

"I've been doing chemistry all day" means "I spent all of today doing chemistry and I am still doing chemistry".  The "I've been doing" structure says that you continue to do what was described. You are actively involved in it right now.

"I was doing chemistry all day" is a statement about the past. It can be used for any day. It usually means "I spent an entire day doing chemistry but that work is done."  The work can be done because this is a different day or because you are not doing chemistry now.

Comment: Good point. I will edit my answer.